# Haskell: Confusion with own data types. Record syntax and unique fields

Tags: haskell

I just uncovered this confusion and would like a confirmation that it is what it is. Unless, of course, I am just missing something.

Say, I have these data declarations:

```
data VmInfo = VmInfo {name, index, id :: String} deriving (Show)
data HostInfo = HostInfo {name, index, id :: String} deriving (Show)

vm = VmInfo "vm1" "01" "74653"
host = HostInfo "host1" "02" "98732"
```

What I always thought and what seems to be so natural and logical is this:

```
vmName = vm.name
hostName = host.name
```

But this, obviously, does not work. I got this.

---

#### Questions

So my questions are.

- When I create a data type with record syntax, do I have to make sure that all the fields have unique names? If yes - why?
- Is there a clean way or something similar to a "scope resolution operator", like `::` or `.`, etc., so that Haskell distinguishes which data type the `name` (or any other none unique fields) belongs to and returns the correct result?
- What is the correct way to deal with this if I have several declarations with the same field names?

---

#### As a side note.

In general, I need to return data types similar to the above example.
First I returned them as tuples (seemed to me the correct way at the time). But tuples are hard to work with as it is impossible to extract individual parts of a complex type as easy as with the lists using "!!". So  next thing I thought of the dictionaries/hashes.
When I tried using dictionaries I thought what is the point of having own data types then?
Playing/learning data types I encountered the fact that led me to the above question.
So it looks like it is easier for me to use dictionaries instead of own data types as I can use the same fields for different objects.

---

Can you please elaborate on this and tell me how it is done in real world?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Haskell record syntax is a bit of a hack, but the record name emerges as a *function*, and that function has to have a unique type.  So you can share record-field names among constructors of a single datatype but not among distinct datatypes.

> What is the correct way to deal with this if I have several declarations with the same field names?

You can't.  You have to use distinct field names.  If you want an overloaded name to select from a record,  you can try using a type class.  But basically, field names in Haskell don't work the way they do in say, C or Pascal.  Calling it "record syntax" might have been a mistake.

> But tuples are hard to work with as it is impossible to extract individual parts of a complex type

Actually, this can be quite easy using pattern matching.  Example

```
smallId :: VmInfo -> Bool
smallId (VmInfo { vmId = n }) = n < 10
```

As to how this is done in the "real world", Haskell programmers tend to rely heavily on knowing what type each field is at compile time.  If you want the type of a field to vary, a Haskell programmer introduces a *type parameter* to carry varying information.  Example

```
data VmInfo a = VmInfo { vmId :: Int, vmName :: String, vmInfo :: a }
```

Now you can have `VmInfo String`, `VmInfo Dictionary`, `VmInfo Node`, or whatever you want.

Summary: **each field name must belong to a unique type**, and experienced Haskell programmers work with the static type system instead of trying to work around it.  And you definitely want to learn about pattern matching.

Comment: In terms of accessor functions, what this actually turns into is a _function_ `vmId :: VmInfo -> Int` which can be mapped, applied, and so on like any other Haskell function.

Comment: Nowadays, GHC *does* allow duplicate field names.

Answer (score 11):

There are more reasons why this doesn't work: lowercase typenames and data constructors, OO-language-style member access with `.`. In Haskell, those member access functions actually are free functions, i.e. `vmName = name vm` rather than `vmName = vm.name`, that's why they can't have same names in different data types.

If you really want functions that can operate on both `VmInfo` and `HostInfo` objects, you need a type class, such as

```
class MachineInfo m where
  name :: m -> String
  index :: m -> String    -- why String anyway? Shouldn't this be an Int?
  id :: m -> String
```

and make instances

```
instance MachineInfo VmInfo where
  name (VmInfo vmName _ _) = vmName
  index (VmInfo _ vmIndex _) = vmIndex
  ...
instance MachineInfo HostInfo where
  ...
```

Then `name machine` will work if `machine` is a `VmInfo` as well as if it's a `HostInfo`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I made it a String because it is required as a string in most parts of the program and I have to "show" it. So to save myself few bits I thought I'd return it as String. I can always "read" it back if I ever need it as an Integer. Is this not the correct way of doing this?

Comment: @r.sendecky: Most Haskell programmers would prefer to keep it as an integer. That way, you can be sure that you don't accidentally set it to something that can't be `read` as an integer, like the empty string. The type system is there to help you avoid bugs, so you should take advantage of it rather than having stuff be "stringly typed".

Answer (score 5):

Currently, the named fields are top-level functions, so in one scope there can only be one function with that name. There are plans to create a new record system that would allow having fields of the same name in different record types in the same scope, but that's still in the design phase.

For the time being, you can make do with unique field names, or define each type in its own module and use the module-qualified name.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this. I thought there must be something at least in design as it seems like a very natural way.

Comment: It's actually not even in the design phase yet. It's still in the complete disagreement phase (by Haskell standards)

Comment: Disagreement is the first phase of design by committee, isn't it?

Comment: any chance of getting Modules and source files dis-tangled? We *could* then define each data type in its explicit (partial) module, all in one source file, as a quick fix...

Answer (score 5):

Lenses can help take some of the pain out of dealing with getting and setting data structure elements, especially when they get nested. They give you something that looks, if you squint, kind of like object-oriented accessors.

Learn more about the Lens family of types and functions here: http://lens.github.io/tutorial.html

As an example for what they look like, this is a snippet from the Pong example found at the above github page:

```
data Pong = Pong
  { _ballPos :: Point
  , _ballSpeed :: Vector
  , _paddle1 :: Float
  , _paddle2 :: Float
  , _score :: (Int, Int)
  , _vectors :: [Vector]

  -- Since gloss doesn't cover this, we store the set of pressed keys
  , _keys :: Set Key
  }

-- Some nice lenses to go with it
makeLenses ''Pong
```

That makes lenses to access the members without the underscores via some TemplateHaskell magic.

Later on, there's an example of using them:

```
-- Update the paddles
updatePaddles :: Float -> State Pong ()
updatePaddles time = do
  p <- get

  let paddleMovement = time * paddleSpeed
      keyPressed key = p^.keys.contains (SpecialKey key)

  -- Update the player's paddle based on keys
  when (keyPressed KeyUp) $ paddle1 += paddleMovement
  when (keyPressed KeyDown) $ paddle1 -= paddleMovement

  -- Calculate the optimal position
  let optimal = hitPos (p^.ballPos) (p^.ballSpeed)
      acc = accuracy p
      target = optimal * acc + (p^.ballPos._y) * (1 - acc)
      dist = target - p^.paddle2

  -- Move the CPU's paddle towards this optimal position as needed
  when (abs dist > paddleHeight/3) $
    case compare dist 0 of
      GT -> paddle2 += paddleMovement
      LT -> paddle2 -= paddleMovement
      _ -> return ()

  -- Make sure both paddles don't leave the playing area
  paddle1 %= clamp (paddleHeight/2)
  paddle2 %= clamp (paddleHeight/2)
```

I recommend checking out the whole program in its original location and looking through the rest of the lens material; it's very interesting even if you don't end up using them.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you cannot have two records in the same module with the same field names. The field names are added to the module's scope as functions, so you would use `name vm` rather than `vm.name`. You could have two records with the same field names in different modules and import one of the modules qualified as some name, but this is probably awkward to work with.

For a case like this, you should probably just use a normal algebraic data type:

```
data VMInfo = VMInfo String String String
```

(Note that the `VMInfo` *has* to be capitalized.)

Now you can access the fields of `VMInfo` by pattern matching:

```
myFunc (VMInfo name index id) = ... -- name, index and id are bound here
```

Comment: Thanks you. It is a shame that Haskell does not have a scope resolution operator for data types. With normal ADT it seems to me a bit tedious to write accessor functions for every atom of ADT. In my case, for instance, I need to extract every part of VmInfo (thanks for the capitalization error pointer) and format it individually for printing in a table.

Comment: If you need to extract every part, you should just pattern match on it in your formatting function.

Comment: OK. I guess I have to revisit the pattern matching as was advised earlier.. Thanks.